# MonetDB is timestamp guaranteed to be unique

Tags: semantics, monetdb, sql-timestamp

The temporal definition in `MonetDB` says that:
"`TIMESTAMP [ '(' posint ')' ]` date concatenated with unique time, precision"

That this mean that if two rows are created with a `DEFAULT TIMESTAMP` that these timestamps are guaranteed to be unique, even if they are created during the same millisecond?

Answer (score 0):

A MonetDB timestamp is (quoting from [`mtime.mal`](https://github.com/snaga/monetdb/blob/master/monetdb5/modules/atoms/mtime.mal)):

```
# @+ Timestamp
# An absolute point of time, as formed by the combination of a date a daytime in GMT
# e.g. 1999-01-31@@23:59:59:000
```

so, your answer is **no, a timestamp is not guaranteed to be unique**.

caveat: I haven't looked at the part of the MonetDB sources which handles `DEFAULT TIMESTAMP`, so I'm only 90% sure about my answer.